# Changing mysql slow query log to public_html path

Tags: mysql, performance, root

I'm stuck, from root mysql I can change my slow query log using this command:

mysql> set global slow_query_log_file = '/var/lib/mysql/log-slow-queries.log';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

However, if I try to change it to to any home directory, I get:

mysql> set global slow_query_log_file = '/home/mydomain/public_html/log-slow-queries.log';  ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'slow_query_log_file' can't be set to the value of '/home/mydomain/public_html/log-slow-queries.log'

This must be a permissions issue?  I am trying to create a PHP script I can access from the web to view the slow query data.  If I try to open the file from PHP, I get this error: 
file_get_contents(/var/lib/mysql/log-slow-queries.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Looking for some help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL can't write on the public_html which its owner is *Apache-user* so it don't let you to set there as the destination of logging slow queries.

Also when you write the result in /var/lib/mysql/log-slow-queries.log *Apache-user* doesn't have access to the content of that file because the owner is *MySQL-user*.

So my best suggestion is to add *Apache-user* to the *MySQL-group* then you can access its log file to read and analyze.

Good luck

Comment: That worked, thank you.  Is there any security issues with my Apache-user part of MySQL-group?

Comment: @ShawMead Ofcourse any feature can be exploited by malicious peoples to attack their victims. this way for example if somebody be able to penetrate into the webserver he can access any other file which is owned by mysql. It will be very dangerous and also very difficult because of high security of web servers like apache and nginx.

Comment: @ShawMead would you choose my answer as the best answer if you find it useful? Thank you.